# Show that $f$ is a measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x+5 &\text{ if } x<-1\\2 &\text{ if } -1\le x<0\\x^2 & \text{ if } x\ge 0\end{cases}$$
Show that $f$ is a measurable function on $\mathbb R$.

**I want to test by the definition of measurable function.**

Please help me..I am unable to proceed anything..

Comment: each of the sub domains is measurable, and each branch of the function is measurable...

Comment: Do you know the definition of measurabel function? SImply check the definition.

Comment: Kidding: this function is too simple to be non-measurable. Seriously: with the right tools, this problem is extremely easy, so I assume that youy don't have the tools. Which tools do u have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
Consider following setting:
$$ f = g \mathbb 1_S + h \mathbb 1_T $$
where $g,h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are measurable and $S\subseteq \mathbb R$ is measurable and $T = \mathbb R\setminus S$.

For each measurable $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ we have
$$ f^{-1}(A) = (g^{-1}(A) \cap S) \cup (h^{-1}(A) \cap T) $$
is measurable.